# ASP.NET membership login by xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, authentication

I have next xml file

```
<employee>
<User>
    <username>master</username>
    <password>123</password>
</User>
```

Next c# file (login.aspx.cs)

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    string username;
    string pwd;
    string CurrentUser = "";
    string CurrentPwd = "";
    bool LoginStatus = false;
    username = Login1.UserName;
    pwd = Login1.Password;
    XmlDocument xmxdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmxdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Loginxml.xml"));
    XmlNodeList xmlnodelist = xmxdoc.GetElementsByTagName("User");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xmlnodelist)
    {
        XmlNodeList xmlnl = xn.ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode xmln in xmlnl)
        {
            if (xmln.Name == "username")
            {
                if (xmln.InnerText == username)
                {
                    CurrentUser = username;
                }
            }
            if (xmln.Name == "password")
            {
                if (xmln.InnerText == pwd)
                {
                    CurrentPwd = pwd;
                }
            }
        }
        if ((CurrentUser != "") & (CurrentPwd != ""))
        {
            LoginStatus = true;
        }
    }
    if (LoginStatus == true)
    {
        Session["UserAuthentication"] = username;
        Session.Timeout = 1;
        Response.Redirect("~/admin");
    }
    else
    {
        Session["UserAuthentication"] = "";
    }
}
```

Login.aspx :

```
<form runat="server">
<div>
<h2 style="color: Green">
Login using Xml file in ASP.NET 4, C#</h2>
<asp:Login  DestinationPageUrl="/admin" ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid"
BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" Height="166px" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate"
Width="264px" FailureText="Username ans password did not match!">
<TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
</asp:Login>

</div>
</form>
```

The code from next url: http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/loginxml.html

Ok, it works great, its recognize when username & password are corrects, but... i want to block access to folder named "admin", only if someone loged in with "master" username and "123" passowrd, he will be available to get in the admin folder content.

I tried to do it by web.config :

```
<location path="admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
            <allow users="master"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

But nothing.. it redirct me again to login page and not to admin folder default.aspx page.
What i need to do? its via web.config or should i block and grant access via admin folder cs code? and how.

Comment: Why don't you use the ASP.Net membership provider?

Comment: @RaimondKuipers Because it will use SQL, and my client want only XML data...and i dont get the idea how to use custom memebership provider with xml data

Answer (score 1):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479021.aspx and then look for ReadOnlyXmlMembershipProvider